# when exactly should root split in a B Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, b-tree

I learned B trees recently and from what I understand a node can have minimum **t-1** keys and maximum **2t-1** keys given minimum degree **t**. Exception being root can have even 1 key.

Here is the example from CLRS 3rd edition Fig 18.7 (Page 498) where **t=3**

min keys = 3-1 = 2
max keys = 2*3-1 = 5

In the **d)** example when L is inserted why is the root splitted when it doesn't violate the B tree properties at the moment (It has 5 keys which is maximum allowed).
Why isn't inserting L into [J K L] without splitting [G M P T X] considered.
Should I always split the root when it reaches the maximum?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several variants of the insertion algorithm for B-trees. In this case the insertion algorithm is the "single pass down the tree" variant.

The background for this variant is given on page 493:

> Since we cannot insert a key into a leaf node that is full, we introduce an operation that splits a full node  (having 2 − 1 keys) around its median key :*key* into two nodes having only  − 1 keys each. The median key moves up into ’s parent to identify the dividing point between the two new trees. But if ’s parent is also full, we must split it before we can insert the new key, and thus we could end up splitting full nodes all the way up the tree.
>
> As with a binary search tree, we can insert a key into a B-tree in a single pass down the tree from the root to a leaf. To do so, we do not wait to find out whether we will actually need to split a full node in order to do the insertion. Instead, as we travel down the tree searching for the position where the new key belongs, we split each full node we come to along the way (including the leaf itself). Thus whenever we want to split a full node , we are assured that its parent is not full.

In other words, this insertion algorithm will split a node earlier than might be strictly needed, in order to avoid to have to split nodes while backtracking out of recursion.

This algorithm is further described on page 495 with pseudo code.

This explains why at the insertion of L the root node is split immediately before any recursive call is made.

Alternative algorithms would not do this, and would delay the split up to the point when it is inevitable.